# How to handle no response of Node.js request module?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I want to save some resources from a website, the resources is separated with many pages so I have to send request page by page. The pages is over 1000+, I used `async.eachSeries` for stable flow. But sometimes, the request module doesn't send the response, so a program is stopped in running.

Below is the code,

```
var pages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, .... , 200];

async.eachSeries(pages, function (page, callback) {

    getData(page, function(){
        console.log('Data saved . page : ' + page);
        callback();
    });

}, function () {
    console.log('All done !');
});


function getData(page, callback) {

    //request data
    var url = "http://finance.naver.com/item/frgn.nhn?code=191420&page="+page;
    request(url, function (err, res, html) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var data = $.html();

            // save to mongoDB
            new Data({
                 data: data,
             }).save(function (err, result) {
                 if (err) console.log('Error !');

                // callback here, to async.eachSeries() knows;
                callback();

            });
        }
    })
}
```

The console

```
Data saved. page : 1 
Data saved. page : 2 
Data saved. page : 3 
Data saved. page : 4 
Data saved. page : 5 
Data saved. page : 6 (stopped here with no progress, sometimes)
```

Most of try is successful, but sometimes program stopped. How can I handle when no response? Is there a way to abandon request and try again?

Comment: You need to both handle errors and implement a timeout.  On either, you will have to decide how many times to retry that page vs. skip it and go on.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you aren't calling your `callback` when either `err` is set or when the `res.statusCode !== 200`.